# Is it possible to apply 'label-position: top' to only one form-item in Element UI

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, element-ui

I'm building web app with Nuxt and Element UI.
I have a question about form component provided Element UI.

This is the screenshot of my web app.

https://gyazo.com/4cf04aa85d0a9bb9a4f2d09a693bbdd6

And there are two el-form-item components(Form Item A and Form Item B).

I would like to apply 'label-position: left' to 'Form Item B', but not 'Form Item A'.
However, there is a problem I already know.

[Problem]

- el-form-item component doesn't have 'label-position' attribute, so if I would like to apply it, I have to apply it to el-form component, but if I do it, all el-form-item components in el-from are applied.

How can I fix it?

This is my code.

```
<template>
  <el-form ref="form" :model="form" label-width="120px" label-position="left">
    <el-form-item label="Form Item A">
      <el-input v-model="form.name"></el-input>
    </el-form-item>
    <el-form-item label="Form Item B">
      <el-select v-model="form.region" placeholder="please select your zone">
        <el-option label="Zone one" value="shanghai"></el-option>
        <el-option label="Zone two" value="beijing"></el-option>
      </el-select>
    </el-form-item>
  </el-form>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        form: {
          name: '',
          region: '',
        }
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var Main = {
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        name: '',
        region: ''
      }
    };
  }
}
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

```css
@import url("//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.13.0/lib/theme-chalk/index.css");
.el-form-item--label-top .el-form-item__label {
  width: auto!important;
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 0 10px;
}

.el-form-item--label-top .el-form-item__content {
  margin-left: 0!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui@2.13.0/lib/index.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <el-form ref="form" :model="form" label-width="120px" label-position="left">
    <el-form-item label="Form Item A" class="el-form-item--label-top">
      <el-input v-model="form.name"></el-input>
    </el-form-item>
    <el-form-item label="Form Item B">
      <el-select v-model="form.region" placeholder="please select your zone">
        <el-option label="Zone one" value="shanghai"></el-option>
        <el-option label="Zone two" value="beijing"></el-option>
      </el-select>
    </el-form-item>
  </el-form>
</div>
```

You can customize a class and apply it to `el-form-item` to achieve the same effect as `'label-position' attribute`